# Как в данном коде сделать три функции, что бы они все работали?

Tags: python

1. Мне нужно что бы две функции my_parse_eng и my_parse_rus делали парсинг сайта, с этим все понятно проблем нет.
   Дальше не могу понять как получившие данные отправить в функцию my_open():, которая записывает все в файл text.csv
2. В функции main, у меня два раза идет обращение к одной и той же ссылке, как сделать нормально, что бы не было дубляжа?

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
import lxml.html
import csv

def my_open():
    with open("text.csv", "w", newline='') as csv_file:
        write = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for i in range(len(my_parse_eng())):
        write.writerow(my_parse_eng([i]))
        write.writerow(my_parse_rus([i]))  

def my_parse_eng(url):
    api = requests.get(url)
    tree = lxml.html.document_fromstring(api.text)
    text_original = tree.xpath('//*[@id="click_area"]//*[@class="original"]/text()')
    return(text_original)

def my_parse_rus(url):
    api = requests.get(url)
    tree = lxml.html.document_fromstring(api.text)
    text_translate = tree.xpath('//*[@id="click_area"]//*[@class="translate"]/text()')
    return(text_translate)
    
def main():
    my_parse_eng("https://www.amalgama-lab.com/songs/t/tones_and_i/dance_monkey.html")
    my_parse_rus("https://www.amalgama-lab.com/songs/t/tones_and_i/dance_monkey.html")
    my_open()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `main` получаете данные из функций, сохраняете в переменные, потом через аргументы передаете в `my_open`:

```
def my_open(eng, rus):
    with open("text.csv", "w", newline='') as csv_file:
        write = csv.writer(csv_file)

        for e, r in zip(eng, rus):
            write.writerow([e])
            write.writerow([r])
            # Вообще, логично было бы писать оригинал и перевод в одну строку в разные колонки:
            # write.writerow([e, r])


...  # Функции my_parse_eng, my_parse_rus без изменений


def main():
    url = "https://www.amalgama-lab.com/songs/t/tones_and_i/dance_monkey.html"
    eng = my_parse_eng(url)
    rus = my_parse_rus(url)
    my_open(eng, rus)
```

Comment: my_open должен принимать либо 1 list либо 2 листа парсинга, т.е делать все через параметр и я так понял может быть одна функция parse_custom_site(arg_url:str)->list.

Comment: Да, можно одну функцию для парсинга сделать. Первое не понял. Там и так два списка передается.

Comment: @Константин в смысле без параметров, а это что `def my_open(eng, rus)`? Вы меня с автором вопроса не путаете случайно?

Comment: Ок, бывает) Тогда напишите ваш комментарий под вопросом, а тут удалите

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, все получилось.